# Can I install Ubuntu alongside VeraCrypt encrypted Windows 10 partition

Tags: dual-boot, encryption, bootloader, veracrypt

I have Windows 10 computer with full disk encryption with VeraCrypt  (standard settings- AES and SHA-256). Can I now install Ubuntu on this hard drive (preferably with full disk encryption too) without messing up the VeraCrypt bootloader?

Answer (score 1):

A safe way to do this is as follows:

1. Temporarily un-encrypt the Windows partition.
2. Resize the Windows partition to leave the space you want the Ubuntu partition to have. (You need to have a partitioning software to boot from to do this.)
3. Re-encrypt the Windows partition, using Veracrypt.
4. Make sure you have a bootable rescue disk from Veracrypt. (They make you have one when you try to encrypt the windows partition.) Test the disk to see that you can boot from it to windows.
5. You can now install Ubuntu into the free re-sized partition, but be aware
   that Ubuntu will over-write the encrypted Windows boot-loader with Grub, and that the only way that you can boot to windows is by using the Veracrypt rescue disk.
6. When using the Veracrypt Rescue disk, do NOT choose to let it 'fix' the Windows bootloader, as then you will not be able to boot Ubuntu. Just let the rescue disk boot to windows.
7. You now have a system that will boot by default into Ubuntu but will allow booting into Windows with the Veracrypt rescue disk.

n.b.
Files on an unencrypted Windows, (Win 7, have not tried Win10), are accessible for anyone using an Ubuntu Install disk, booting to 'try' the Ubuntu system, and then mounting the NTFS partition. All files (unencrypted by third-party encryption software) including Administrator files are accessible, copyable onto USB media, and deletable without a trace that Windows has been accessed.

So, it's probably worth the annoyance of using a Veracrypt bootable disk to keep the Windows partition encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Did you here about 2 pendrives solution?

Here are the steps I took:

1. Create two system partitions on the hard disk:
   a) Linux MX – ext4 filesystem
   b) Windows 10 – NTFS filesystem.
2. Installing Linux on a system partition with an ext4 file system.
3. During the installation of Linux I chose the system encryption option
   and the bootloader location on a pendrive (it is possible)
   and this is a function built into the Linux  operating system. After
   going through the setup procedure, the system partition was fully
   encrypted with the LUKS encryption system, but I might as well
   encrypt it with VeraCrypt after installation.
4. Linux was installed, however, without using a bootloader pendrive
   (GRUB) will not start.
5. In BIOS, we set the boot order to
   a) flash drive
   b) cd / dvd rom
   c) hard drive
6. Now, after inserting the flash drive with the Linux bootloader, we can
   boot the system and decrypt the system partition.
7. Close the system and insert the Windows 10 installation media (CD or
   bootable flash drive).
8. Install Windows, then install Veracrypt on it and start the encryption
   process.
9. After full encryption, reboot the system. Only the Veracrypt bootlader
   (Windows 10) is displayed NOW.
10. We enter our password and we are in decrypted Windows 10.
11. To start Linux, put the pendrive with bootloader (GRUB) and start the
    computer. Our computer should boot into the Linux bootloader.
12. In my case, however, it did not happen, I don’t know why, but
    VeraCrypt stops booting GRUB from pendrive.
13. I solved by creation a second bootable flash drive with SuperGrub2
    program. (I created a bootable USB flash drive with Linux and
    [SuperGrub2](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/)).
14. Then I connected the GRUB Linux pendrive and the second SuperGrub2
    pendrive. Now BIOS recognized bootloader. In the SuperGrub2 menu, I
    chose detection of bootloaders on my computer.

We will see Linux bootloader / GRUB and Windows 10 bootloader.
Now we can select the system we want to boot after decryption.

Now our Linux system is double protected (LUKS + VeraCrypt or VeraCrypt + Veracrypt) + 2 flash drives to run. Took from: [https://hacker-tips.com/language/en/dual-boot-veracrypt-windows-linux-2/](https://hacker-tips.com/language/en/blog/2021/02/16/dual-boot-veracrypt-windows-linux-2/)

Answer (score 0):

I would not attempt it. Too often we see requests for help because an "along-side another OS" installation failed and the tools we have to resolve can only deal with unencrypted disks... Please correct me if I'm wrong...
I am unsure if decrypting the whole disk, install Ubuntu and encrypt again is an option in VeraCrypt? I had a brief look at their website but did not find anything helpfull.
My advise: either install Ubuntu as a VM in Windows 10 using VMWare or VirtualBox or install Ubuntu on a separate bootable disk.

Comment: Or add another hard drive (this is easy with SATA) and install Ubuntu there. Switch the boot drive from the BIOS boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

On UEFI boot systems, [this article](https://medium.com/@lankycyril/using-veracrypt-with-a-uefi-dual-boot-setup-27d1eacbf36b) claims one can do it by first installing the dual boot, encrypting windows system partition, reversing boot loader order from: `VeraCrypt> Grub (which gets skipped after whole diskencryption)` to: `Grub>VeraCrypt`. To reverse the order of the bootloaders apparently one could use EasyUefi, and this [link lists](https://superuser.com/questions/1247300/how-to-make-uefi-bios-start-grub-not-windows) more ways to reverse the order.

I have not yet been able to verify this approach. Nor have I found a way to perform a dual boot Windows 10 + Ubuntu 20.04 with VeraCrypt whole disk encryption.